# How to link OCaml object file with Core module?

Tags: ocaml, linker-errors, ocaml-core

I have simple program, which uses function from `Core.Std` module, e.g.:

```
open Core.Std
let _ = List.last [1;2;3]
```

I can compile and link it by `ocamlfind` or `ocamlbuild`:

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -package core -linkpkg -thread app.ml 
ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -pkgs core -tag thread app.native
```

But I don't know how to compile and link such file using "normal" OCaml compiler:

```
ocamlc -c -I ~/.opam/system/lib/core_kernel/ -I ~/.opam/system/lib/core/ app.ml 
ocamlc ~/.opam/system/lib/core_kernel/core_kernel.cma ~/.opam/system/lib/core/core.cma app.cmo
```

Last of above commands gives the following error:

```
File "_none_", line 1:
Error: Error on dynamically loaded library: /home/maciej/.opam/system/lib/stublibs/dllcore_kernel_stubs.so: /home/maciej/.opam/system/lib/stublibs/dllcore_kernel_stubs.so: undefined symbol: caml_ba_alloc
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ocamlfind ocamlc -only-show …` to see the full command constructed by ocamlfind . Your error points towards some missing transitive dependencies of Core and an old version of OCaml and Core.